# Video thumbnails in List

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble displaying video thumbnails in a list.  The file path next to the image works, but not the thumbnail.  Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Videos/");

String[] videoFileList = path.list();

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textfilePath = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(videoFileList[position]);
        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, videoFileList));
}
```

}

My row.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Thumbnail"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/FilePath"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The file path is displayed correctly, but not the image.  I suspect the problem is somehow in my row.xml, but there are no errors. If I direct it to just 2 videos that I manually set the path to, using 2 unique strings, it works fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am sure that u are not getting the filepath what u are getting is filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are getting file video path  not the video name? I think you are getting video name because in videoFileList array you are storing the string that comes after "/Videos/" . That means you are not storing the path but the file that are in '"videos"' folder. To get the thumbnail you need the file path not the file name. To get the videos only from videos folder you can use coursor like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
      String folder="bluetooth";
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            proj, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[] { "%" + folder + "%" }, null);
     videopath=new ArrayList<String>();
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            videopath.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
      setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidThumbnailList.this, R.layout.row, videopath));
  }
}
```

and modefy your code this way

1.

```
  public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
```

Replace with below

```
 public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> videopath) {
 super(context, textViewResourceId, videopath);
```

2.

```
  videoFileList[position]
```

replce with

```
  videopath.get(position)
```

**Update:** If the file extension is not of video type then above code will give error so update your onCreate

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      videopath=new ArrayList<String>();
      File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/bluetooth/");
      File[] files = path.listFiles();
      for( File f : files ){


                  String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                  videopath.add(absPath);


      }

      setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidThumbnailList.this, R.layout.row, videopath));
  }
```

}

The updated code will populate all the files those are in bluetooth folder, video and non-video both and will return thumbnail for the video.

Comment: You are correct, it is the filename showing up.  In your code, is the path the string "folder"?  I am getting a few errors.   To clarify, these videos are currently not in the gallery, because when they are downloaded, they will have a non-video extension.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind checking whether the thumbnail created is NULL or not. As per the documenation, it says

> Create a video thumbnail for a video. May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.

Comment: Ok, but it works with the exact videos when I manually set the path?

Comment: Pls post the path.Might be its not able to reach the file.

Comment: The path is sdcard/Videos/.  It reaches the file fine because the filename is displayed correctly.

Comment: I suggest you use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() cos sometimes it can be /mnt/sdcard/Videos/.. or mnt/sdcard-ext/Videos/..something like this String movieurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Videos/Wildlife.wmv";

Comment: I tried that, but I want to point it to the directory so I can get all the videos in the directory.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the array position?

Comment: For debugging purpose, try harding the file path and check whether you get the thumbnail or not. Once you get that check whether it matches with the one in array. :)

Comment: The absolute path works :/, but I need the file extension on the video.  This kind of defeats my purpose of listing the files if I have to point it to the exact file...

Comment: May be you can have the file names with extension in the array and while showing it in the textview, you can remove the extn. That is one way to go. Pls accept/upvote the answer if the discussion helped. cheers.